# Set shortcut for eyedropper (color picker) in firefox

Tags: firefox

How do you set a custom shortcut for firefox 66?

How do i set a custom shortcut for the eyedropper tool?
By default the tool does not have a shortcut.

[image: Firefox eyedropper menu]]

Comment: Got the thumble weed badge for this :(

Answer (score 2):

There is a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1177108) open for quite a long time at Mozilla for this. When open, the eyedropper has [some shortcuts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Keyboard_shortcuts#Eyedropper).

I've ended up installing a [dedicated extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/search/?q=eyedropper) for this !

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete solution, but the best available if you don't want to use a specific addon. Activating the Eyedropper will take two clicks.

---

1. Add the Developer menu icon to the toolbar: Right click the toolbar where there is the AdBlock icon (or any addon you chose to install), then select Customize and add the Developer menu:

[image]

2. Click the Developer menu icon you added and pick the Eyedropper:

[image]

Comment: That's very helpful!  Nice plan B until they actually put in a shortcut for us.